# Что именно и когда возвращать пользователю в PHP в случае ошибки?

Tags: php, исключения

Меня интересует вопрос о возврате сообщения или ошибки в PHP. В каких случаях показывать 500 ошибку пользователю с небольшой информацией о случившемся, а когда лучше выводить текст ошибки.

То есть вопрос заключается в том, чтобы четко разделить вывод Exception и его сообщения клиенту.

Скажем, что сейчас есть несколько вариантов развития событий:

1. В случае серьезных ошибок на стороне сервера (закрыт доступ на
   создание директорий, ошибка подключения в серверу отправки почты и
   прочие) показывать страницу 500 ошибки с текстом.
2. В случае ошибок со стороны пользователя (формат файла не прошел
   проверку, запрашиваемые данные не найдены, отсутствует папка или
   файл для работы и прочие) показывать сообщение (вернуть текст
   ошибки).
3. В случае любых ошибок возвращать текст ошибки или "не удалось", а
   сами ошибки логировать.

То, что я делаю сейчас можно назвать библиотекой разработки (может и микро-фреймворк). В ней я хочу реализовать подход работы с ошибками и не могу точно определить, как это делать лучше.

**UPD**

Конкретно вопрос возник тогда, когда я разобрался, что я буду выводить в качестве результата работы хелпера по работе с файлами, но не смог решить, что именно возвращать при закрытом доступе при рабоет с папками.

Comment: У пользователя вашего фрейворка должна быть возможность самому обрабатывать ошибки и выводить нужную информацию. Вам же нужно создать столько исключений, чтобы пользователь мог выводить либо детальную информацию, либо факт ошибки.

Comment: @ArchDemon, да, спасибо за совет, я думаю в сторону возвращать `true` в качестве успеха, `exception` в случае ошибки. А вот что делать с ним пусть решает программист.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос, и, на самом деле, очень простой.

Я не вижу здесь трех вариантов развития событий. Если присмотреться, то пункты 1 и 3 это одно и то же. А пункт 2 ошибкой вообще не является. То есть в результате у нас есть один-единственный сценарий для обработки ошибок в приложении: просто пишем один маленький error/exception handler, который и занимается тем что показывает юзеру 500 страницу с извинениями, а саму ошибку пишет в лог.

Проблемы же валидации входящих данных, ошибками, по сути, не являются. Это нормальная реализация бизнес-логики. Если она реализуется с помощью исключений - завернуть эту самую валидацию в try-catch и ловит в нем исключения строго определенного типа - ошибки валидации. Все остальное должно в целости и сохранности долетать до нашего маленького error/exception handler-а.

Главное в этом деле - не пытаться делать работу за РНР.

У меня есть такое подозрение, что упомянутый "хелпер по работе с файлами" пытается проверить каждый файл и папку на существование перед тем как обратиться к ним. И потом - натурально - встает вопрос что делать, если проверка не прошла. Ну так вот надо проверять поменьше. Вообще, надо всегда следовать правилу: если не знаешь, что делать в случае ошибки - не делай на неё проверку. РНР сам ругнется, когда надо, возникнет ошибка или исключение, её поймает наш хендлер... и далее как обычно.

Сам хендлер должен определять, на боевом он сервере или на тестовом. В первом случае выводить 500 страницу с извинениями, а во втором - развесистое и подробное сообщение об ошибке. Плюс логировать ошибку, разумеется.

Если подытожить:

- при возникновении ошибок в приложении возвращать пользователю 500 страницу с извинениями
- при валидации пользовательского ввода возвращать пользователю результат валидации

Comment: А вот такой вопрос тогда. Надо загрузить файл. Чтобы его загрузить надо: проверить сам файл, проверить, что папка загрузки существует (если нет, то создать) и открыть права на запись в нее, загрузить файл, закрыть права. Очевидно, что валидация файла вернется клиенту, а что в случае ошибки при работе с директорей?

Comment: при возникновении ошибок в приложении возвращать пользователю 500 страницу с извинениями

Comment: то есть получается, что все, что не является валидацией пользовательских данных есть 500. А тогда вопрос такой: если в качестве результата работы модуля работы с файлами возвращать `true` в случае успеха, текст, в случае ошибки валидации и `exception` в случае ошибки серьезной. То разработчик сможет сам уже контролировать процесс и принимать решения о том, как ему лучше поступить. Как считаете, этот способ хорош для системы? Я просто делаю систему для разработчика, а не сервис.

Comment: Это совсем уже оффтопик, но модуль должен предоставлять два метода - validate и upload. Вот validate и должен разговаривать про ошибки. Желательно в виде массива. А upload вообще ничего не должен возвращать.

Answer (score 0):

Если ошибка должна быть решена пользователем то нужно выводить подробную информацию об этом и дать удобную возможность ее решения

Если эта системная ошибка то пользователю нельзя знать подробности, эти подробности могут быть использованы для взлома системы